# SQL Update query and a Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have tables like:

- `Materials` (MaterialID, Name)
- `Teacups` (TeacupID, Description, FriendlyName, MaterialID)

With data like:

**Materials**:

```
(1, 'Glass')
(2, 'Porcelain')
(3, 'Iron')
```

**Teacups**:

```
(1, 'Desc1', 'Name1', 1)
(2, 'Desc2', 'Name2', 1)
(3, 'Desc3', 'Name3', 1)
(4, NULL, 'Name1', 2)
(5, NULL, 'Name2', 2)
(6, 'Desc6', 'Name3', 2)
(7, 'Desc7', 'Name1', 3)
(8, NULL, 'Name2', 3)
(9, NULL, 'Name3', 3)
```

How do I update all descriptions (whether NULL or not) to have the same descriptions as the Teacups with `MaterialID=1`, matched by the FriendlyName

So the data needs to look like:

**Teacups**:

```
(1, 'Desc1', 'Name1', 1)
(2, 'Desc2', 'Name2', 1)
(3, 'Desc3', 'Name3', 1)
(4, 'Desc1', 'Name1', 2)
(5, 'Desc2', 'Name2', 2)
(6, 'Desc3', 'Name3', 2)
(7, 'Desc1', 'Name1', 3)
(8, 'Desc2', 'Name2', 3)
(9, 'Desc3', 'Name3', 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `JOIN clause` in the `UPDATE` statement. Try this..

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.Description = B.Description
FROM   Teacups A
       JOIN (SELECT Description,
                    FriendlyName
             FROM   teacups
             WHERE  MaterialID = 1) b
         ON a.FriendlyName = B.FriendlyName 
Where A.MaterialID != 1
```

Comment: check the column name materailid in where condition?? Not working due to incorrect column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tUp
   SET tUp.Description = t1.Description
  FROM Teacups tUp
  JOIN Teacups t1       
    ON t1.FriendlyName = tUp.FriendlyName 
   and tUp.MaterialID <> 1 
   and t1.MaterialID   = 1
 --and tUp.Description <> t1.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use MERGE statement as below:

```
 MERGE INTO Teacups as trg
 USING (
         SELECT FriendlyName, Description FROM Teacups WHERE MaterialID = 1
       ) AS src
 ON trg.FriendlyName = src.FriendlyName
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET trg.Description = src.Description;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can create a temp table and insert the values of this query:

```
SELECT * from teacups WHERE MaterialID = 1; --insert into table 'temp'
```

Then you can update your table:

```
UPDATE teacups SET description = temp.description WHERE teacups.FriendlyName = temp.FriendlyName;
```

Comment: Please try to run your query and check the result.